# How can I get the last date of month while increasing date on monthly basis?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code which works on a increament of month. However, after feburary it shows last day as 28 for each month. How can I get the actual last day of each month while increasing each month.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time

Start_Date = date(2010, 01, 01)
End_Date = date(2010, 01, 31)
Final_startdate = date(2011, 12, 01)

while Start_Date < Final_startdate:
    print Start_Date
    print End_Date

    Start_Date = Start_Date + relativedelta(months=+1)
    End_Date = End_Date + relativedelta(months=+1)
```

This is what I get:

2010-01-01

2010-01-31

2010-02-01

2010-02-28

2010-03-01

2010-03-28

2010-04-01

2010-04-28

2010-05-01

2010-05-28

2010-06-01

2010-06-28

2010-07-01

2010-07-28

2010-08-01

2010-08-28

Comment: @glibdud : Thank you for referring to the duplicate question. I got my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I changed last line of code for end_date to the one below and it works. I got my desired answer.

```
End_Date = Start_Date + relativedelta(months=+1,days=-1)
```

The answer I got is

2010-01-01

2010-01-31

2010-02-01

2010-02-28

2010-03-01

2010-03-31

2010-04-01

2010-04-30

2010-05-01

2010-05-31

2010-06-01

2010-06-30

2010-07-01

2010-07-31

2010-08-01